# Are there any species whose descendants can meet their ancestors from 100 generations back?

Tags: evolution, dna, reproduction, lifespan

I.e. Humans can sometimes meet even their great-great-grandparents, but are there any species that can be alive at the same time as their great-great-……-great-grandparents? I imagine it would be those species with a long lifespan and an early age of first reproduction.

Comment: Do the species have to be animals?  Many trees would seem to qualify.  Then there's the Greenland shark: https://www.newscientist.com/article/2100823-worlds-oldest-vertebrate-is-a-shark-that-may-live-for-500-years/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it comes under the category of “idle amusement” rather than being a real problem in biology faced by the poster.

Comment: @David: Is it an official rule, that questions must relate to a "real problem in biology faced by the poster" ?

Comment: @KaPy3141 I quote from the [Tour] "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." And in the [Help on  Asking Questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) "are more than just mindless social fun"

Comment: I take it that questions must not be motivated by the reactions or interactions they cause. I think I get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [cryopreservation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5395684/#:%7E:text=Cryopreservation%20is%20a%20process%20that,theoretical%20interest%20and%20practical%20relevance.) works quite well for many species, including multicellular animals. So you can freeze the ancestor and wait until the descendant is there, then unfreeze them. A good recent example in the news would be the [Siberian worms](https://www.livescience.com/63187-siberian-permafrost-worms-revive.html) that woke up after being frozen in permafrost for a very long time.

Cryopreservation is routine in laboratories, to freeze ancestors and compare to descendants; see the [Long Term Evolution Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._coli_long-term_evolution_experiment). It doesn't work well for every organism of course. In principle [it might work for humans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3275130/#:%7E:text=Cryopreservation%20is%20the%20use%20of,Cryopreservation%20is%20not%20freezing.).

Some bacteria will [sporulate](https://www.microscopemaster.com/sporulation.html), and in spore form they can persist for thousands of years theoretically. They don't even need cryopreservation. There are other organisms that do something similar as well.